# Up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

My notes state that if we only consider groups of size $n$ 'up to isomorphism', the elements of our group are a fixed set= {$a_1,..,a_n$}. I get that groups with the same structure but different labels for the elements are isomorphic, but I don't really understand the term 'up to isomorphism'.

Answer (score 3):

"Up to isomorphism" just means that two groups that are isomorphic are considered the same group.

For example on the set $\{a,b\}$ you can define two groups, one whose neutral element is $a$, and one whose neutral element is $b$. However those two groups are isomorphic, thus *up to isomorphism* there's only one group.

Comment: Ok, I get that "up to isomorphism" means that isomorphic groups are the same. However, I still do not understand why if we are considering groups of size $n$ up to isomorphism, the elements of our group are fixed.

Comment: @yons After you fix the $n$ elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$, any group with $n$ elements (no matter what those elements might be) is isomorphic to a group with your fixed $n$ elements.  So, up to isomorphism, every $n$-element group consists of your fixed $n$ elements.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Could you expand upon: 'Any group with $n$ elements is isomorphic to a group with your fixed $n$ elements'.

Comment: @yons Suppose you're given an $n$-element group whose elements are $b_1,\dot,b_n$. The bijection from $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ to $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ that sends each $b_i$ to the corresponding $a_i$ becomes an isomorphism of groups if you define an appropriate group structure on $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$.

Comment: So up to isomorphism, all groups of size $n$ can have their elements relabelled as {$a_1,..,a_n$} if the group structure is defined appropriately?

Comment: @yons: Yes. Basically it says the labels are effectively just that, names for the group elements; to use a non-group example, up to relabelling isomorphism, the sets $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ $\{\text{one}, \text{two}, \text{three}, \ldots\}$ and $\{|,||,|||,\ldots\}$ are the same if the arithmetic structure is defined appropriately.